# How to shutdown windows 8 with python 2.7 using a timer

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm doing a small project to learn more about python 2.7. Im making a shutdown timer, I got the GUI all set up and I just need the command to shutdown windows 8. The cmd command is: shutdown /t xxx.

I have tried the following:

```
import subprocess
time = 10
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "/t", "time"])


import os
time = 10
os.system("shutdown /t %s " %str(time))
```

Both don't work.
Any help appreciated, I'm using Windows 8 so I think solutions with windows 7 are different.

Thanks for the answers, here is the shutdown timer i made:

https://github.com/hamiltino/shutdownTimer

Comment: What happens with each -- error messages, stacktrace, what?

Comment: figured it out, I needed to add /s. cmd use to pop up and disappear with the shutdown help menu displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to the [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) should be the sequence of program arguments(strings) OR a single string.

Try following:

```
import subprocess
time = 10
subprocess.call(["shutdown.exe", "/t", str(time)]) # replaced `time` with `str(time)`
# OR subprocess.call([r"C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe", "/t", str(time)])
#      specified the absolute path of the shutdown.exe
#      The path may vary according to the installation.
```

or

```
import os
time = 10
os.system("shutdown /t %s " % time)
# `str` is not required, so removed.
```